# Complex repository dependencies in C without waste of disk space

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

Assume that I have 4 git repositories with C files. The base repository `pair`, on which the others depend, declares a type.

`pair.h`:

```c
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b; 
} PAIR;
```

Two other repositories `add` and `multiply` define operations on this type and both contain `pair` as a submodule or subtree:

`add.c`:

```c
int add (PAIR p) {
    return p.a + p.b;
}
```

`multiply.c`:

```c
int multiply (PAIR p) {
    return p.a * p.b;
}
```

The last repository `calc`, which contains `add` and `multiply` as submodules or subtrees, contains a program which uses both operations.

`calc.c`:

```c
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    PAIR p;
    p.a = atoi(argv[1]);
    p.b = atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("sum = %d\n", add (p));
    printf("product = %d\n", mul (p));
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that, if I clone `calc` recursively, then `pair` will be contained twice in the directory tree of `calc`, although it is only needed once. If the real structure gets more complex with several dependency stages, it leads to a huge waste of disk space.

How can this be organized in a disk-space-friendlier way?

It would be fine for me to have only one "current version" of every repository to be able to work with.

Comment: I guess both repositories point to a version of pair, but in theory you could update one without the other. Hence the need for two "versions" of pair?

Comment: Related: [Avoid duplication of same git submodule within one project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74126663/11082165), [Duplicate submodules with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4115817/11082165), [How to reduce the memory footprint for multiple submodules of the same source?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44585425/11082165)

Comment: @Jeppe One version of `pair` would be enough for me. Nevertheless, with git submodules/subtrees, `pair` will be put twice into the directory tree of `calc`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `calc`, `add` and `multiply` can all use the same version of `pair`, I would declare `add`, `multiply` and `pair` as submodule of `calc`.

And I would remove `pair` from `add` and `multiply`: those two can look for `pair` outside their repository (`../pair` instead of `./pair`).

That way:

- you can do a recursive clone of `calc`
- only one version of `pair` remains
- `calc` is in charge of getting the right versions of `pair`, `add` and `multiply`